# Chrome text shadow showing when set to 0

Tags: google-chrome, css

So, I'm in the process of building a website designer and I have come across something strange, if you set the `text-shadow: 0 0 0 someColor` on a element the shadow is actually applied, I have made a fiddle where this is very clear here **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h4Nze/1/)**.

Is this a bug?
[image]

Comment: @Doorknob: `text-shadow`, unlike `box-shadow`, doesn’t have an “extend” part — it’s syntactically invalid and is also thrown out =)

Comment: @minitech Oh, well okay then. This is weird O_o

Comment: I’d chalk it up to an inconsistency between the anti-aliasing of regular rendered text and text shadow. (It probably doesn’t spend as much “effort” on the shadow or something.)

Comment: @minitech I'd rather say that it's because if you render two half-transparent objects (such as a half-filled pixel) on top of each other, both are visible

Comment: @JanDvorak: Oops, that makes sense, thanks :) Ideally, it wouldn’t, but I suppose there’s no other way.

Comment: @minitech ideally, rendering would do beam-tracing instead of alpha-compositing after antialiasing, but I can't imagine that in practice if only for performance reasons - but I can imagine an approximation to that (depending on how much data you want to store with a pixel)

Comment: maybe the browser should special-case the situation when two things should overlap exactly - but, then again, why not handle that at the CSS level?

Comment: And why would you set those values? if you don't want a shadow set `text-shadow: none;` otherwise you'll have one at (0,0) offset and with 0 blur, which is not the same as 0 spread

Comment: @koala_dev There is no spread, on the `text-shadow`

Comment: @Pinocchio I know, that's why you need to set `text-shadow: none;` instead of `text-shadow: 0 0 0;`

Comment: @koala_dev Well, long story short, i don't use `none` because the values are in an array. ie. `['0', '0', '0', '#000']` And then it's joined.

Comment: @Pinocchio then you'll have to indicate `none` in your format somehow. `null` instead of an array?

Comment: @JanDvorak I am quite fine finding a way around it, that's not an issue.

Comment: I can just do, if joined string indexOf 0 0 0 then joined string = '';

Comment: @Pinocchio: Or just if `!arr[0] && !arr[1] && !arr[2]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug in that it's not an incorrect implementation of the spec; the spec implies that a shadow is generated as long as the computed value is something other than `none`. The *only* values that can compute to `none` are `none` or `initial`.

Text shadows are drawn similarly to box shadows. Because of this, most of the behavior of text shadows follows the spec for [box shadows](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow). Nowhere in either spec is it stated that a value with all zeros should generate no shadow. All it says is that either property can take one of two possible values: `none`, or a comma-separated list of one or more `<shadow>` value groups, each of which corresponds to a set of values: in the case of `text-shadow`, it's `[ <length>{2,3} && <color>? ]#` as given in [its own spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-shadow-property). As long as you have a value that isn't `none`, either spec assumes a shadow will be drawn and specifies all the behavior based on that assumption.

For both properties, even if you don't specify a color, both specs state that `currentColor` should be used (it says in prose that it's "taken from the `color` property" or "the resulting color of the ink that it shadows"; the result in code is `currentColor`).

Since the shadow is always drawn for a value other than `none`, and zero lengths result in a shadow that's exactly the same size as the text, what happens here then is probably the result of compositing two or more layers of semitransparent pixels due to anti-aliasing of the glyphs as well as the shadow (as stated in the comments). This applies not only to text shadows, but also box shadows, an archetypal example of which would be in [a box with rounded corners](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/h4Nze/26), where the only hints of anti-aliasing are on the rounded corners themselves, and not the straight edges of the box. This also happens in all browsers, at least based on testing and prior experiences.

With all that said, if you absolutely cannot accept `none` as a value, you can always specify `transparent` for the color. The shadow will still be drawn, but since it's completely transparent, [you won't see it](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/h4Nze/27).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a text-shadow, I suggest setting text-shadow: none;

```
text-shadow:none;
```

Comment: I know how this can be fixed, with `text-shadow: none;` for example, but that's not the problem, the problem is this should not really happen when there is no blur set on the element.

Answer (score 0):

> Optional. This is a  value. If not specified, it defaults to 0. The higher this value, the bigger the blur; the shadow becomes
>   wider and lighter.

The blur property does not indicate no blur when set to zero. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow

Comment: sure, the shadow is there, but it's perfectly aligned with the text so it shouldn't be visible. At least, in theory.

Comment: The blur property *does* indicate “no blur” when set to zero, if I may interpret “sharp” as meaning “no blur”. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow

Comment: @minitech it does not, however, indicate "no shadow"

Comment: @JanDvorak: I never claimed that it did. I’m refuting this answer’s claim that *“the blur property does not indicate no blur when set to zero”* when it obviously does.

Comment: So, we are at the conclusion that it doesn't anywhere say 0 = no blur, but in reality you would have thought it was right?

Comment: @Pinocchio 0 means no blurring (ideally), definitely not no shadow

Comment: That's what I meant.*

Answer (score 0):

text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF; these properties not for hide or show. move shadow up down, move shadow right left and blur level 0 is clear.

if you want hide Shadow Then : Write "text-shadow:;" but dont set any value it should be empty.

sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a page builder and want initial "empty" values (which they're not empty, the first two zeroes indicate positioning and the last how much blur) you may just want to set the color as a default to the element background color.  Or you can change your blur value to -1.

```
text-shadow: 0 0 -1px red;
```

The other option I can think is to have them enable text-shadow and then put in your 0 0 0 red using an if else statement.  Pseudocode:

```
if text-shadow option is checked
    use text-shadow:0 0 0 red;

else
    use text-shadow:none;
```

Good luck.

Comment: I know how this can be fixed, with `text-shadow: none;` for example, but that's not the problem, the problem is this should not really happen when there is no blur set on the element.